# Use String hashCode() Method?

Tags: java, string, java-7, hashcode, java-8

From link :

http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_string_hashcode.htm

[Relationship between hashCode and equals method in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17027777/relationship-between-hashcode-and-equals-method-in-java)

[Good hashCode() Implementation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16629893/good-hashcode-implementation)

But i cant understand  about the hashcode .

Here's an example:

```
public class StringDemo {
    public static void main(String args[]){
        String strob1="first string";
        System.out.println(strob1.hashCode());
    }

    }
```

This simple program give me output:`-5468287`

Can anyone tell me :
How it give me output:`-5468287` ?

Comment: The source code is available online or in your JDK installation.

Comment: Are you simply confused what hash codes are for in general? I looked a bit and found this: http://isagoksu.com/2009/development/java/what-is-hash-code/

Comment: I can understand the *why* question, but *where*? In `String.hashCode` of course, where else.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

String's [**hash code**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#hashCode%28%29) is computed as:

```
s[0]*31^(n-1) + s[1]*31^(n-2) + ... + s[n-1]
```

using `int` arithmetic, where `s[i]` is the `i`-th character of the string, `n` is the length of the string, and `^` indicates *exponentiation*. (The hash value of the empty string is zero.)

Hence, the overflow of this integer computation can easily occur, resulting in negative according to [**Java Language specification-15.8.2**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.18.2):

> If an integer addition overflows, then the result is the low-order
>   bits of the mathematical sum as represented in some sufficiently large
>   two's-complement format. If overflow occurs, then the sign of the
>   result is not the same as the sign of the mathematical sum of the two
>   operand values.

Answer (score 1):

Hashcode is used to allow objects to be stored in a `Map` object (or with other data structures that use hashes).  The goal of a hashcode is to provide a unique value for objects with different values, but produce the same hashcode if the object is the same.  This is essentially a unique index for an object to be looked up by.

A `HashMap`, which implements the `Map` interface, depends on a good implementation of `hashcode()` to evenly distribute among differing objects for optimal performance.  With this it can provide O(1) average case speed to operations such as `get()`.

So if you ever intend on using a custom object that you make as a `key` for a `HashMap` you should provide an implementation of `hashcode()` which most IDE's will assist you with.

edit: in your example output of `-5468287` that is its hashcode value.  If you look at the hashcode of `"first strings"` which only differs by one character it should be a vastly different number, which is a good thing because it helps evenly distribute objects inside your Map.

Comment: The `hashCode` method is for any data structure that uses hashes, not exclusively `Map`. Any data structure that uses a hash table uses hashes, and there are other structures that use hashes, like a hash trie. Or any other case where you want to be able to quickly eliminate the possibility of two items being equal without needing to check every single member.

Comment: @AJMansfield You are right, I was referring to the most common use case.  I edited my wording to make it more general.

Answer (score 1):

In essence, you won't call it yourself unless you are coding a data structure (which you most probably don't have to).

However, you'll often implement one. Nowadays almost all IDE provide auto-generation of equals & hashCode. I'd advise to just use that for the moment; whenever you implement equals, also generate a hashCode implementation.

Answer (score 1):

Why? The method is defined in java.lang.Object. Any class you define inherits it.

Refer [enter link description here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#hashCode%28%29).

What? I suggest you study more about what is hashing. [Wiki hash functions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_function).