# Correct way to implement Map<MyObject,ArrayList<MyObject>>

Tags: java, hashmap, multimap

I was asked this in interview. using `Google Guava` or `MultiMap` is not an option.
I have a class

```
public class Alpha
{
     String company;
     int local;
     String title;
}
```

I have many instances of this class (in order of millions). I need to process them and at the end find the unique ones and their duplicates.
e.g.

```
instance --> instance1, instance5, instance7 (instance1 has instance5 and instance7 as duplicates)
instance2 --> instance2 (no duplicates for instance 2)
```

**My code works fine**

declare datastructure

```
HashMap<Alpha,ArrayList<Alpha>> hashmap = new HashMap<Alpha,ArrayList<Alpha>>();
```

Add instances

```
for (Alpha x : arr)
{
    ArrayList<Alpha> list = hashmap.get(x); ///<<<<---- doubt about this. comment#1
    if (list == null)
    {
        list = new ArrayList<Alpha>();
        hashmap.put(x, list);
    }
        list.add(x);
}
```

Print instances and their duplicates.

```
for (Alpha x : hashmap.keySet())
{
    ArrayList<Alpha> list = hashmap.get(x); //<<< doubt about this. comment#2
    System.out.println(x + "<---->");
    for(Alpha y : list)
    {
        System.out.print(y);
    }
    System.out.println();
}
```

Question: My code works, but why? when I do `hashmap.get(x);` (comment#1 in code). it is possible that two different instances might have same hashcode. In that case, I will add 2 different objects to the same List.

When I retrieve, I should get a List which has 2 different instances. (comment#2) and when I iterate over the list, I should see at least one instance which is not duplicate of the key but still exists in the list. I don't. Why?. I tried returning constant value from my `hashCode` function, it works fine.

If you want to see my implementation of `equals` and `hashCode`,let me know.

Bonus question: Any way to optimize it?

Edit:

```
@Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (obj==null || obj.getClass()!=this.getClass())
            return false;
        if (obj==this)
            return true;
        Alpha guest = (Alpha)obj;
        return guest.getLocal()==this.getLocal()
                && guest.getCompany()  == this.getCompany()
                && guest.getTitle() == this.getTitle();
    }

@Override
public int hashCode() {
    final int prime = 31;
    int result = 1;
    result = prime * result + (title==null?0:title.hashCode());
    result = prime * result + local;
    result = prime * result + (company==null?0:company.hashCode());
    return result;
}
```

Comment: Your implementation of the `equals` should remain untouched because it should support the actual definition of equality for your object. You might be able to optimize it by changing your `hashCode` implementation though. Your target is to keep the hash buckets smaller, so that you have less objects for `.equals` check.

Comment: Yes, we'd really need to see your equals and hashCode to tell you if it's working correctly. Also *"My code works ... I should see at least one instance which is not duplicate ... I don't"*, so does it work or not? I don't understand.

Comment: This might be helpful - http://stackoverflow.com/a/16629910/738746

Comment: It looks like you're comparing Strings with `==`. Are you aware [that might be wrong](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java)? It depends on where `company` and `title` come from but this may very well be why your equals doesn't work the way you are expecting.

Comment: I don't see any duplicate instance where it should not be. In other words, I see expected/normal behavior. I think my code is wrong, hence the question.

Comment: @Radiodef, yes, but in this case, it is ok. They are all in String pool.. Good point, though.

Comment: So are you saying your code actually works correctly but you think it shouldn't? I don't really understand the question then. Why do you think your code is wrong? Besides the 1 thing I already pointed out I don't think there's a problem.

Comment: @Radiodef, Yes. I think the code is wrong because I am still not clear how hashmap works. Where exactly does key.equals() check takes place? when doing get() or when doing put()?

Comment: OK I see what you are asking. I think @LuiggiMendoza has answered your question: the point being that while HashMap uses `hashCode` to determine a location in its internal table, it uses `equals` to determine equality of keys. Two keys with the same hashCode can exist in a HashMap simultaneously if they are unequal.

Comment: *"Where exactly does key.equals() check takes place? when doing get() or when doing put()?"* `equals` is used all the time: both `get` and `put` might result in a call to `equals`.

Comment: @Radiodef, Thanks, I understand your answer. Could you please post it as an answer? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> it is possible that two different instances might have same hashcode

Yes, but `hashCode` method is used to identify the index to store the element. Two or more keys could have the same `hashCode` but that's why they are also evaluated using `equals`.

From [`Map#containsKey`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#containsKey(java.lang.Object)) javadoc:

> Returns `true` if this map contains a mapping for the specified key. More formally, returns `true` if and only if this map contains a mapping for a key k such that (`key==null ? k==null : key.equals(k)`). (There can be at most one such mapping.)

---

Some enhancements to your current code:

- [Code oriented to interfaces](https://stackoverflow.com/q/383947/1065197). Use `Map` and instantiate it by `HashMap`. Similar to `List` and `ArrayList`.
- Compare `String`s and `Object`s in general using `equals` method. `==` compares references, `equals` compares the data stored in the `Object` depending the implementation of this method. So, change the code in `Alpha#equals`:

  ```
  public boolean equals(Object obj) {
      if (obj==null || obj.getClass()!=this.getClass())
          return false;
      if (obj==this)
          return true;
      Alpha guest = (Alpha)obj;
      return guest.getLocal().equals(this.getLocal())
              && guest.getCompany().equals(this.getCompany())
              && guest.getTitle().equals(this.getTitle());
  }
  ```
- When navigating through all the elements of a map in pairs, use [`Map#entrySet`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#entrySet()) instead, you can *save* the time used by `Map#get` (since it is supposed to be O(1) you won't save that much but it is better):

  ```
  for (Map.Entry<Alpha, List<Alpha>> entry : hashmap.keySet()) {
      List<Alpha> list = entry.getValuee();
      System.out.println(entry.getKey() + "<---->");
      for(Alpha y : list) {
          System.out.print(y);
      }
      System.out.println();
  }
  ```

Comment: So the code is correct? I had doubt about it, thought it would be better to confirm here.  Also, any way I can optimize it further?

Comment: @IanMcGrath [What does it mean to “program to an interface”?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/383947/1065197)

Comment: @Luigi, Good point I will change HashMap<Alpha,ArrayList<Alpha>> hashmap  to Map<Alpha,List<Alpha>> hashmap

Comment: And note that [`get`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#get%28java.lang.Object%29) uses the same `(key==null ? k==null : key.equals(k))` evaluation as `containsKey`.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza, understood. Wow, it is as if the light bulb went on in my brain now. Thank you so much for your patience and answering in detail.

Answer (score 1):

> Use `equals` along with `hashCode` to solve the collision state.

Steps:

- First compare on the basis of title in `hashCode()`
- If the title is same then look into `equals()` based on company name to resolve the collision state.

Sample code

```
class Alpha {
    String company;
    int local;
    String title;

    public Alpha(String company, int local, String title) {
        this.company = company;
        this.local = local;
        this.title = title;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return title.hashCode();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (obj instanceof Alpha) {
            return this.company.equals(((Alpha) obj).company);
        }
        return false;
    }
}

...

Map<Alpha, ArrayList<Alpha>> hashmap = new HashMap<Alpha, ArrayList<Alpha>>();

hashmap.put(new Alpha("a", 1, "t1"), new ArrayList<Alpha>());
hashmap.put(new Alpha("b", 2, "t1"), new ArrayList<Alpha>());
hashmap.put(new Alpha("a", 3, "t1"), new ArrayList<Alpha>());

System.out.println("Size : "+hashmap.size());
```

Output

```
Size : 2
```

Comment: sorry if my question was not clear. I want to understand where is the equal with key done in this case. Thanks.